# Mysql - a little help on my business logic

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products (`id`, `stock`, `availability`,....) in an eshop and so far my business logic is:

A product is available in the following cases:

- if availability=0 and stock>0
- if availability>0 and stock>=0

I use availability to inform the customers of the number of days it will be shipped after purchase, and I set availability = 0 to determine that the product will be available only while stock > 0. This way, when i set availability=0 and stock=0 the product will therefore become unavailable.

I'm not sure if

```
select * from product where (availability=0 and stock>0) or (availability>0 and stock>=0)
```

will work, it seems to simple to be true. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't you mean `availability>0 or stock>0`?

Comment: It's a combination of 2 separate cases

Comment: Yes, it should be `avilability > 0 and stock > 0`

Comment: Please read my question again, youre missing my point. Availability can be 0 as long as stock>0

Comment: Got it, in that case your query looks good to me.

Comment: @bikey77 look at the snippet below, i posted

Comment: "A product is available for purchase if availability>0 AND ALSO if stock>0." Then your condition should be `availability>0 AND stock>0`.

Answer (score 1):

use this in your situation:

```
select *from products where availability>=0 and stock>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by combining them since both are checking for stock>0

```
Select * from product where stock>0;
```

This is because as long as stock > 0, it almost doesn't matter what availability is. It will still be unavailable when stock = 0 as you specified, but you said it should be visible when availability = 0 and when >0 as long as stock > 0. Assuming that you're not making availability <0 you won't need to include it in your query.

Comment: it's not correct to use OR, it'll show products with 0 in stock but availability>=0. you need to use AND

Comment: @Developer: I allow orders for products with stock=0 as long as they are available (availabilty>0)